# How does the routing in Hugo templates work?

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization

I am trying to design my own theme starting from [`blank`](https://github.com/Vimux/blank). The test site builds fine and is indeed empty but functional.

I however fail to understand how the routine in themes work. Specifically, my problem is that I do not see where the main skeleton for the final web page is - that one that will build `<header>`, `<body>`, etc. I expected to find there the logic of switching between views: what to parse when looking at the home page, what at a blog entry, what at a standalone page, etc.

To take the example of this starter theme, I see `https://github.com/Vimux/blank/tree/master/layouts/index.html`, but it is just the definition of **one of the** `main` blocks. There are other such definitions in `https://github.com/Vimux/blank/tree/master/layouts/_default` for instance.

**Where do I code the logic/decision to use a specific template file? (one of the several with the definition of `main`)**

I expect that some "routing" (not dynamic one - a routing that is then compiled into a set of pages with links to other pages) must be defined somewhere where you say that the page `/` is generated from `<something>`  and a page `/blog/hello-world` is generated from  `<something else>`.

Comment: I recommend looking at how "archetypes" work in Hugo. I think this is the most common way to define different content types (blog versus 'page') and then build templates for each that are specific to the type. Hugo tries to make assumptions about what template to use, based on the URL / site directories. An item in the blog/ directory uses the blog template, for example. It is also possible to set the "type: blog" in the frontmatter of an item, to specify the template to be used. https://gohugo.io/content-management/archetypes/ https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Great question.**

The answer is rather suprising... especially when you are coming from Jekyll or a similar SSG.

**The logic/decision to use a specific template file is implicit**.

This means that a file in the root of the 'content' directory named '_index.md' uses the 'layouts/index.html' template, while a page with another name in the same directory uses the 'layouts/pages/single.html' template. When that layout file is not found/does not exist, it will fall back to the 'layouts/_default/single.html' template.

More on this can be found at https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/.